# save a string with xamarin in a cross-platform project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm using xamarin (for android and for iphone) and I want to save one string.

In fact, I'm using a JSON parser and I pass a string object trough intents, so I wanted to save the object into a SQLite but I have some difficulties, so I'm asking why don't I save just that string in memory and parse it when I want the object?

What do you think about it?

I don't think that we have to use a framework or a lib to make it, but I see no informations about that on the xamarin official website!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> so I'm asking why don't I save just that string in memory and parse it when I want the object?

As long as you can guarantee that the application will continue running, then this will work.

However, for a general Android case I would advise against this - as for the general case, Android is free to terminate your application at any time. When your application is then later recreated Android will take the user direct to your page and pass the same Intent to your page - but at that stage your cached object will not be in memory.

> I don't think that we have to use a framework or a lib to make it

Not sure what you are asking about here, but Xamarin provide several complete application samples, and there are a few frameworks around too (e.g. I write [this one](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross))

Comment: Okay thanks. This is a very great job :-) but in java android, there is the SharedPreferences, and for IOS, I think you can save file, isn't it? I just have to save one string. For the samples thanks, I already read about those quickly, and noone used those sort of storage (directly the sqlite or ado.net)